# How can i access a static variable by a class name in Java?

Tags: java, class, oop

I have many classes which have the same static attribute (staticAttr) and i have another class which accepts the class name and accesses its staticAttr of the class name specified.
How can i do this. Please help me!
Thanks.

EDIT:

```
        public class Group_name1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
        {
            public static Group_name1 staticVar;

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.group_name1);
                staticVar = this;
            }
         }
         public class Group_name2 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
            {
                public static Group_name2 staticVar;
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.group_name2);
                    staticVar = this;
                }
             }
```

Now my problem is to have an access to the static variable of these classes in another class by just giving a class name string. Now the class should can be used to get the staticVar which contains the object.

Currently, i have created seperate classes for every class mentioned above to refer to the staticVar. But i feel its redundant and bad style of programming because every class i write for refering to the above classes does the same function. The only thing that changes is the Class name reference

**Group_name1 grpActivity;**
**Group_name2 grpActivity;**

These are my current implementations. But i want to just use the class name to refer the static variable

```
class GroupNameListener1 extends Thread
{
    Group_name1 grpActivity;
        public void run()
        {
               grpActivity = Group_name1.staticVar;
               /*
                    do something
                */
        }
}
class GroupNameListener2 extends Thread
{
    Group_name2 grpActivity;
        public void run()
        {
               grpActivity = Group_name2.staticVar;
               /*
                    do something
                */
        }
}
```

Comment: Use reflection Luke http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: You can use reflection, but that can get messy. Why not have a common interface which is implemented by all your classes, with a static method defined (rather than a static variable) which each class can implement to return as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Like this  :

`ClassWithStaticVariable.VariableName`

if you have

```
class A {
  public static String a = "test"
}
```

then you can access it like this :

```
class B {
  public void test() {
    System.out.println(A.a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you have something like

```
class A {
  public static String str = "test"
}
```

and in you code you have a method like

```
void methodA (A someObj) {
```

in this method you can access the static variable

as

```
   A.str
```

or

```
  someObj.str
```

Comment: @Vamshi the syntax `someObj.str` although accepted it's not recommended though, so prefer `A.str`

Answer (score 0):

What you have is very bad design. Short of reflection there is no way to solve this generically as you designed it.

I believe what you are trying to do is attaching *meta data* to your classes. A very simple way to do that would be to keep a global map holding the data (and work with the class instead of its name):

```
public class MyClassMetaData {
    private final static Map<Class<?>, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        dataMap.put(MyClassA.class, "TestA"); // one method of initialization
        dataMap.put(MyClass2.class, "Case2");
        // one line per class...
    }

    private MyClassMetaData() {
    }

    public static String getMetaData(Class<?> theClass) {
        return dataMap.get(theClass);
    }
}
```

But you need to remember to add a line that puts the data into the map into the static block when you add another class.

If you need to initialize data dynamically, access to the map may need to be synchronized.